# Upload Files in S3 with parenthesis in Key causing SignatureDoesNotMatch Error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am trying to Upload files in c# to an s3 bucket.

```cs
try
{
    var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
    {
        InputStream = obj.InputStream,
        Key = obj.Name,
        BucketName = obj.BucketName,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
    };

    // initialise the transfer/upload tools
    var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

    // initiate the file upload
    await transferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
    
    response.StatusCode = 201;
    response.Message = $"{obj.Name} has been uploaded successfully";
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Ex)
{
    response.StatusCode = (int)s3Ex.StatusCode;
    response.Message = s3Ex.Message;
}
```

It is working fine, but now i need to upload files which contains parenthesis in key name. And there i got the error **"SignatureDoesNotMatch" - Forbidden.**
Does anyone has any idea how to solve this?

UPDATE:
This Key is working:
`39650_Mandanten.json`
This one not
`(39650)_Mandanten.json`

Best Regards, Fabian

Comment: If you are sure its because of the key and not something coincidental with this specific document then please show a failing example key. Maybe its something else within the key. For example whitespaces tend to make problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the parenthesis. The problem is that it starts with that character. The parenthesis is allowed but only in the middle of the key name.

Key names need to start with a character or a number.

Please read naming conventions here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html

Comment: `(39650)_Mandanten.json` is object not bucket.

Comment: trying key:  prod/File_(39274)_Mandanten.json is also failing!

Comment: try lowercase first letter.

Comment: @HugoHiasl same result...